# Dynamically add key/value array of names into array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an array of names. I also have an array of objects. I would like to iterate through the array of objects and also iterate through the the array of names and add the name into the objects. For example, name[0] goes into object[0], and so on.

I have this code:

```
this.individualSrv.GetDataById(this.org[i].userId).subscribe(data => {
  this.names.push(data.fullname)
  for (var x = 0; x < this.org.length; x++) {
    for (var i in this.names) {
      this.org[x]['name'] = this.names[i]
    }                    
   }                  
})
```

Right now, the last name in the array is added to each object in the array.

Comment: post the sample array/object here

Comment: Why are you using two indexes? `this.org[x]['name'] = this.names[x]` should be enough, the nested for is unnecessary, though you should loop the longest array first. May you share some examples, though?

Comment: seems you already are looping through this.org cuz `GetDataById(this.org[i].userId)`, I assume that you will get only one user per id, then why another two loops? you simply can `this.org[i].name=data.fullname` after `this.names.push(data.fullname)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to nest 2 loops to do that. Just make sure that both arrays have the same length.

```
this.individualSrv.GetDataById(this.org[i].userId).subscribe(data => {
  this.names.push(data.fullname)
  for (var x = 0; x < this.org.length; x++) {
      this.org[x]['name'] = this.names[x]
   }                  
})
```

Comment: thanks so much. i was thinking that different arrays need different iterations